# How toString is called in userdefined Exception?

Tags: java, tostring

Here how the toString() method executes no explicit call is made to it? can anyone please explain the control flow of it

```
class MyException extends Exception
{
    String str1;
    MyException(String str2) {
       str1=str2;
    }
    public String toString(){ 
       return ("Output String = "+str1) ;
    }
}

class CustomException{
    public static void main(String args[]){

       try{   throw new MyException("Custom");   }
       catch(MyException e){ System.out.println(e); }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you don't understand about the control flow, could you be more specific?!

Comment: There's nothing special about exceptions herre - `println(Object)` simply calls `toString` if the parameter isn't null...

Comment: here how the toString function is called

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Did you confuse `exp` and `e` in your catch block?

Answer (score 0):

When an object is passed to `System.out.println` it's `toString()` method is called (so this result can be displayed), whatever this object might be (Exceptions are also objects).

So, when you do:

```
catch(MyException exp) { 
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

System.out.println takes `e`, call's it's `toString()` and displays this result onto console.

Answer (score 0):

Since `toString()` is part of `Object`, which all objects inherit from, [`System.out.println(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) (`out` is a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)) **knows** there is a `toString()` implementation and it uses it ([`String.valueOf(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) is called first).

Since `toString` has been overridden - it uses the specified implementation.

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of the `PrintWriter.println(Object)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) says:

> Prints an Object and then terminates the line. This method calls at first `String.valueOf(x)` to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

The method `String.valueOf(Object)` uses the parameter's `toString()` method unless it is null.

This is why `toString()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

[`System.out.println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) prints an Object and then terminate the line.

This method calls at first [`String.valueOf(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

[`String.valueOf(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) return if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned, in your case, it's

> Output String = Custom

Answer (score 0):

When you call `System.out.println(e)`:

```
     public void println(Object x) {
         String s = String.valueOf(x);
         synchronized (this) {
             print(s);
             newLine();
         }
     }
```

This method calls `String.valueOf(x)`:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Do you see `obj.toString()`? 
You can reference source-code here [PrintStream.println](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29), [String.valueOf](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)